# How do I capture command output in PostgreSQL using a JDBC connection?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

If I run a PostgreSQL command that generates output as a stream of text, such as `vacuum full verbose analyze`, how do I capture its output using a JDBC connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is available in the warnings of the `Statement` object that was used to run the command:

```
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
stmt.execute("vacuum verbose foobar");
SQL Warning warn = stmt.getWarnings();
if (warn != null)
{
  System.out.println(warn.getMessage);
}
```

Theoretically there can be chained warnings, so you might want to use a loop, that checks `SQLWarning.getNextWarning()`. Check the JDK JavaDocs for more details.